# Scala: What'd be the idiomatic way to test equally spaced frequencies in array?

Tags: algorithm, scala

I have a Scala application and have the following use case. Given a `numberOfDates: Int` and an `optimalFrequencyInDays: Int` I need to find the frequency in days closest to this optimal frequency in days that will give me evenly spaced triggers within this number of days. As extra conditions the trigger also has to happen at the beginning and at the end ; furthermore, the number of days between any two triggers can not be smaller than the optimal frequency e.g.

```
val numberOfDays = 260
val optimalFrequencyInDays = 2
// equally spaced answer is 3 i.e. 87 triggers Seq(0, 3, 6, 9, .. , 255, 259)

val numberOfDays = 260
val optimalFrequencyInDays = 124
// equally spaced answer is 130 i.e. 3 triggers Seq(0, 130, 259)
```

I think the rule to solve this is:

```
val solution = (numberOfDates % optimalFrequencyInDays ) match {
  case 0 => numberOfDates / (((numberOfDates / optimalFrequencyInDays) / 2) + 1)
  case _ => numberOfDates / (((numberOfDates / optimalFrequencyInDays + 1) / 2) + 1)
}
```

In words, the formula `(length / 2 + 1)` gives me the range of odd numbers that will produce the number of triggers I need for an evenly spaced solution e.g. for 20 would be `20 / 2 + 1 = 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2` If I divide the length by the result of that formula I get the evenly spaced frequency I need.

The output of this use-case is encoded in an array of Booleans of the form `Array(1, 0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0, 1)` meaning whether there was a trigger at the day of that index. What is the idiomatic Scala way to test that the triggers are equally spaced except the last that can be evenly spaced +- 1 because there is no perfect fit.

Comment: So which is it, `Array[Boolean](true,false,false,...)` or `Array[Int](1,0,0,...)`?

Comment: In reality is an `Array[Boolean]` but I wrote an `Array[Int]` because I am too lazy to type true false true false  but good catch and can switch from one to the other with a simple map step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a collection of `1`s and `0`s, and you want to test if the `1`s are evenly spaced except for the final spacing which could be an outlier.

```
triggers.mkString        // one long string of 0's and 1's
        .split("(?=1)")  // multiple strings, all starting with '1'
        .dropRight(2)    // drop the final `1` and the possible outlier
        .sliding(2)      // pair up the rest
        .forall{         // all the same?
           case Array(a,b) => a == b
           case Array(_) => true  // too few to matter
        }
```

This will handle an empty `triggers` collection as well as a collection of one or more `1`s (no `0`s).

**update**

This will work with an `Array[Boolean]`, either by mapping it to an `Array[Int]` or by changing the `split()` pattern to `split("(?=true)")`.

You can test the "outlier" for its off-by-one condition by saving the intermediate collection after the `split()` and testing its `head` against its `init.last`.

Answer (score 2):

You can take indexes of elements with ones, and then calculate the difference between each pair of elements to calculate intervals. Then you just have to check if all elements but last are equal and if the last element is equal +/- 1.

```
val triggers = Vector(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);

val intervals = triggers.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 == 1).map(_._2).sliding(2).map { case Vector(a, b) => b - a }.toVector

val allButAllAreEqual = intervals.init.forall(_ == intervals.head)
val lastIsEqualToAllPlusMinusOne = intervals.last == intervals.head || intervals.last + 1 == intervals.head
```